# Safely write to file in parallel with pathos.multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pathos

`pathos.multiprocessing` is known to have advantage over `multiprocessing` library in Python in the sense that the former uses `dill` instead of `pickle` and can serialize wider range of functions and other things.

But when it comes to writing `pool.map()` results to file line-wise using `pathos`, there comes up some trouble. If all processes in `ProcessPool` write results line-wise into a single file, they would interfere to each other writing some lines simultaneously and spoiling the job. In using ordinary `multiprocessing` package, I was able to make processes write to their own separate files, named with the current process id, like this:

```
example_data = range(100)
def process_point(point):
    output = "output-%d.gz" % mpp.current_process().pid
    with gzip.open(output, "a+") as fout:
        fout.write('%d\n' % point**2)
```

Then, this code works well:

```
import multiprocessing as mpp
pool = mpp.Pool(8)
pool.map(process_point, example_data)
```

But this code doesn't:

```
from pathos import multiprocessing as mpp
pool = mpp.Pool(8)
pool.map(process_point, example_data)
```

and throws `AttributeError`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-a6fb174ec9a5> in <module>()
----> 1 pool.map(process_point, example_data)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/pool.pyc in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    128         '''
    129         assert self._state == RUN
--> 130         return self.mapAsync(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
    131
    132     def imap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=1):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/processing-0.52_pathos-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/pool.pyc in get(self, timeout)
    371             return self._value
    372         else:
--> 373             raise self._value
    374
    375     def _set(self, i, obj):

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'current_process'
```

There is no `current_process()` in `pathos`, and I cannot find anything similar to it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the `pathos` author.  While your answer works for this case, it's probably better to use the fork of `multiprocessing` within `pathos`, found at the rather obtuse location: `pathos.helpers.mp`.

This gives you a one-to-one mapping with `multiprocessing`, but with better serialization. Thus, you'd use `pathos.helpers.mp.current_process`.

Sorry, it's both undocumented and not obvious… I should improve at least one of those two issues.

Comment: Thank you! Here what appears to work in the end: `pathos.helpers.mp.currentProcess().getPid()`

Answer (score 2):

This simple trick seems to do the job:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from pathos import multiprocessing as pathos_mp
import gzip

example_data = range(100)
def process_point(point):
    output = "output-%d.gz" % mp.current_process().pid
    with gzip.open(output, "a+") as fout:
        fout.write('%d\n' % point**2)

pool = pathos_mp.Pool(8)
pool.map(process_point, example_data)
```

To put differently, one can use `pathos` for parallel computation, and ordinary `multiprocessing` package for getting id of current process, and this will work correctly!